# How to reduce the font size of the placeholder in mobile media query

Tags: html, css

I am having a very weird issue here. I can manage to reduce the font size of the placeholder for my desktop version but not for my mobile phone media query. I began with the desktop version first and I am using max width of 480 pixel or less with the following code:

```css
div.practice_diary input::placeholder {
    color: #6A5ACD ;
    opacity: 1;
    position:relative;
    left: 6em;
    font-size: .1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="practice_diary">
  <form class="signup-form" action="practice_diary_form.php" method="POST">

    <label>User ID</label>
    <br></br>
    <input text="text" name="user_uid" placeholder="User ID">
    <br></br>
    <label>Student's First Name</label>
    <br></br>
    <input text="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Student's First Name">
    <br></br>
    <label>Student's Last Name</label>
    <br></br>
    <input text="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Student's Last Name">
    <br></br>
    <label>Lesson Title</label>
    <br></br>
    <input text="text" name="lesson_title" placeholder="Lesson Title">
    <br></br>
    <label>Describe Lesson: For example: Did you practice counting? fingering?</label>
    <br></br>
    <textarea name="describe_lesson" placeholder="Describe Lesson"></textarea>
    <br></br>
    <div class="practice_diary_last_two_questions">
    <label>Hours of practice</label>
    <br></br>
    <input text="text" name="hours_practice" placeholder="Hours of Practice">
    <br></br>
    <label>Date of Practice</label>
    <br></br>
    <input text="text"  placeholder="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($date); ?>">
    <br></br>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Enter Diary</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

But nothing seems to be changing when viewing it from my mobile phone but bear in mind that it is working for desktop version...

Comment: Please add the HTML and the original CSS without media queries.

Comment: You might want to start and fix your html markup first

Comment: Are you referring to my use of the br tag? I know that I should use the <br /> but I just feel that it has a better line break using the older format

Comment: here you added your css in javascript

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this in your css file

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
input::placeholder {
font-size: 1em;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
        input {
            font-size: 24px;
            color: tomato;
            border: 1px solid;
        }

        div.practice_diary input::placeholder{
            font-size: 24px;
            color: tomato;
        }

    @media screen and (max-width: 30em) {

        input {
            font-size: 14px;
            color:slateblue;
        }

        div.practice_diary input::placeholder{
            font-size: 14px;
            color:slateblue;
        }

    }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="practice_diary">
    <input type="text" placeholder="hello there..."/>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your code, try using a bigger font-size, 0.1em is not visible or maybe mobile font-size is not working for you because of cache issue. so, you can also try clearing your browser cache.